# Linq - operating on lists of lists

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I have a list of class `A`, class `A` contains a list of class `B`.  I want to operate on all instances of `B` within all instances of class `A`.

```
var myListOfA = new List<A>();

class A
{
    public List<B> ListOfB;
}
```

How can I iterate over all `B` i.e. `foreach(var b in myListOfA.ListOfB){}`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx):

```
foreach(var b in myListOfA.SelectMany(a => a.ListofB))
```

See it in action at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/2LDQS).

Comment: Ahh, I had tried `Select` which didn't work (seems obvious now), spot on. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

another way that works well for how i think of nested objects is:

```
(from A objA in myListOfA
    from B objB in objA.ListOfB
        select objB);
```

this will "fan out" the list of b's within all the a's in the main list.

Comment: Note that this is syntactic sugar for `SelectMany`, but I agree, its more readable sometimes.

Comment: yeah it's definitely just another way of using selectmany, just wanted it on here for reference purposes